# how can I add a specific namespace to my xsd

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

I added a namespace to my xml but I have no idea what to do in my xsd to be valid. I add two namespaces: `sysadmin` and `network`

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<computers


xmlns:sysadmin="http://admin.ecolefrancomaghrebine.net/"

 xmlns:network="http://reseau.ecolefrancomaghrebine.net/">

<computer id="1">
<model>Macintosh PowerBook G3</model>
<sysadmin:service>21/09/32000</sysadmin:service>
<network:ip>134.158.69.203</network:ip>
<system>
<sysadmin:nom>MacOS</sysadmin:nom>
<version>X</version>
</system>
<ram sysadmin:unite="Mo">384</ram>
<disk sysadmin:unite="Go">20</disk>
<processor>Motorola PowerPC G3</processor>
<clock>400 Mhz</clock>
<administrator src="jr.jpg">Jean-René Rouet</administrator>
</computer>

</computers>
```

My xsd code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?altova_samplexml file:///C:/Users/OMARO-TAYTA/Documents/xml/computers.xml?>

<xs:schema
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:sysadmin="http://admin.ecolefrancomaghrebine.net"
xmlns:network="http://reseau.ecolefrancomaghrebine.net"
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">


<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2008 sp1 (http://www.altova.com) by info (info) -->
    <xs:element name="computers" type="typecomputers"/>
    <xs:complexType name="typecomputers">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="computer" type="typecomputer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="typecomputer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="service" type="sysadmin:string" />
                                    <xs:element name="ip" type="network:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="system">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="nom" type="sysadmin:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ram">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:attribute name="unite" type="sysadmin:string"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="disk">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                            <xs:attribute name="unite" type="sysadmin::string"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="processor" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="clock" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="administrator">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I get error:

```
'sysadmin:string' must refer to an existing simple or complex type.
Error location: xs:schema / xs:complexType / xs:sequence / xs:element / @type
Details
src-resolve.4.2: Cannot resolve declaration or definition 'sysadmin:string'.
```

Comment: Why are you using `sysadmin:string`?  Why not just use `xs:string`?

Answer (score 1):

In XSD you need to define a separate schema document for each namespace used in your XML instance; you need to use xs:import to reference the schema document for another namespace if you refer to any elements (etc) defined in that namespace.

Comment: Then you did it wrong, and I can't tell how you did it wrong unless you show me.

Comment: i created a new shema for spacename network                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:network="http://reseau.ecolefrancomaghrebine.net/" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"/>
and an other for sysadmin                                                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sysadmin="http://admin.ecolefrancomaghrebine.net/" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"/>

Comment: then i used the import                                              <xs:import namespace="http://admin.ecolefrancomaghrebine.net/sysadmin" schemaLocation="C:\Users\chahla\Desktop\tp     valide\computer4\sysadmin.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="http://reseau.ecolefrancomaghrebine.net/network" schemaLocation="C:\Users\chahla\Desktop\tp valide\computer4\network.xsd"/>                                   but i still get an error